# Reduce messy words into word seed

Tags: python, api, seed

For example, spotify API song genres:

```
['alternative rock', 'comic', 'funk rock', 'garage rock', 'indie rock', 'pop rock', 'post-grunge', 'rock']   

['g funk', 'gangster rap', 'hip hop', 'pop rap', 'rap', 'west coast rap']   

['canadian pop', 'dance pop', 'pop', 'pop christmas']
```

Three lists represent three song's genres.But such genres look quite messy, and I could easily "extract" the "genre seed", that is three songs are

```
rock
rap
pop
```

respectively

How could I reduce such messy words into word seed? 
thx

Comment: You will need some sort of mapping between genres and the 'genre seed'.

Comment: Do you have a finite list of seed words already?

Comment: Yes, I do have list of seed words like "pop" "rock"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have a list of seed, we could, for example, count an occurences of each seed in genre and return the one with max weight.
Let's say that seed list is called "seed" and genre list is called "genre". We should cross-check all seed-genre combination, and add weight to some structure.

```
def max_seed_return (seeds, genres):
    # appending weigths to dictionary
    weights= {seed:0 for seed in seeds}
    for genre in genres:
        for seed in seeds:
            if seed in genre:
            weights[seed]+=1
    max_weight, result = 0, None
    # getting result genre with biggest weigth
    for seed, seed_weight in weights.items:
        if seed_weight>max_weight:
            max_weight=seed_weight
            result=seed
    #returns it or None if no seeds is found in genres
    return result
```